# iOS: Touch Event in UIScroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

I have tried so many thing to get touch inside a `UIScrollView` but I'm not getting how to do it.

Actually I want to touch inside a `UIScrollView` and get the location of subview (which i have touched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with gesture recognizers. For detect single tap location use `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)] autorelease];
[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender{ 
    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:myScrollView];
    CGPoint tapPointInView = [myScrollView convertPoint:tapPoint toView:self.view];
}
```

To convert that `tapPoint` to self.view you can use [`convertPoint:toView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint%3atoView%3a) method in UIView class